# How to configure the server APIs in angular2 components?

Tags: angular, deployment

I am developing a web app using Angular2 as the front end. However, I noticed that in my angular code, I need to set server api like `localhost:9000` to get data. In the future if I want to deploy my work I think I should have some config file to specify it. For the backend part I know how to set this server port, but how can I do that in Angular? How can I just set it once and make it both works in server and angular?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 :**

Create new file in angular 2 project **proxy.conf.json** add below code to configure API

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:9000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

in your package.json modify below

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

No need to set your api full path in service.ts file in above example :

Like your api :  **http://localhost:9000/users/me**

in the following code use in **service.ts**

**private resourceUrl = 'users/me';**

**Option 2 :**

Add below code in **.angular-cli.json** file in your project

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {
    },
    "serve": {
      "port": 4201
    }
  }
```

**Option 3 :**

in **package.json** file set **"start": "ng serve --port 4201"**